# Accessing the public file in a view of a controller. Rails is considering current controller's path as relative path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using `Rails 3.2.5`. I have a file that is currently kept in my public folder 
eg: /public/files/file.swf
 This file loads several dependent swf files within it which are also present in the /public/files folder.

This "file.swf" is being accessed in my index.html for my index action of /member/mycontroller

```
<embed Xscale="scaleToFit" scale="noscale" width="100%" height="100%" name="fieldObj" id="fieldObj" authorative="userid,level,sport"

src="/files/file.swf" 

TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/>
```

The file does not load since the file is being searched for in the /views/member/mycontroller folder.

If i specify the absolute path of file.swf it loads, but the dependent swf files that are called within it fail to load since they are still being looked for in the /member/mycontroller folder.

IS there some way we can configure to skip looking in  member/mycontroller and look for it directly in the public/files folder? I had similar issues while rendering a partial of different controller.

Comment: How do you load this file ?

Comment: Try removing the `/` before the path

Comment: @acts_as_geek: If I remove it would take current controller's path i.e. /member/mycontroller but file is in public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a "member/mycontroller" folder in the public folder and put the files in that.